# Dynamic google-like map with large amount of data

Tags: javascript, performance, google-maps, optimization, google-maps-api-3

I would like to create a large 2D map (100x100 fields, every field 190x110 px) that should be zoomable and scrollable.

The background image is relatively simple, just some images (stones, water, etc.) repeated over and over, but randomly ordered. So I can either create the background image as a whole, resulting in a really large file, or create it on the fly using the little stone/water-images.

On every field there will be an item. I must be able to detect when one of them (and which) is clicked. To make it even more complicated, the images of the items will contain transparent areas that should not react to a click. If item A overlays item B, a click on a transparent area of A should trigger the function for B.
There are about 20 images for the 10.000 fields, so they can be reused.

I already tried to create my map with canvas, but the performance in some browsers/computer is really bad (firefox works fine for me but not for a friend of mine, opera has huge performance problems for both of us)

One of my ideas was to use a library based on the google-maps-script, but I fear that then I'll have to create every clickable item as a marker resulting in an other performance problem.

Do you have an idea how to create the descriped map without performance problems? It's fine if the map takes some seconds to load, as long as the navigation on the page isn't blocked.

Comment: You can try http://openlayers.org/ library

Comment: I was going to suggest as above, another (slightly left field) idea could be Seadragon: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/gg413360.aspx